# bridge WAN interface with TUN interface except openvpn port

Tags: linux, iptables, openvpn, tunnel

I want to make a bridge between `eth0` (static WAN) and `tap0` (TUN), but leave 1194 port for openvpn on `eth0`.

Is it possible? How to achieve it using *iptables*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. Once an interface enters a bridge, it loses its IP address, so there is no way to reach a port on it.

However, the same functionality which eth0 had before being enslaved to the bridge, passes to the bridge. So you may use port 1194, or port 2000, or whatever, on the bridge br0.

In particular, if you want to set up an OpenVPN server, its port 1194 **must** be opened on the bridge interface, not on eth0.

There also more complex scenarios possible, including the simultaneous use of many different VPNs, OpenVPN or not, both as a server and as a client, which can be easily accommodated, should the need arise.

Comment: So, if I occupy port on br0 on openvpn server, then it would not be forwarded to openvpn client?

Comment: @Orient:  Not sure I understand: if your OpenVPN server uses port 1194, then the client will have to use port 1194. If you also want to use the same pc as an OpenVPN client to a **different** OpenVPN, then use another port (let us say, for instance 2000) for the client and its server.

Comment: I want to have WAN IP behind the proxy. [Here](http://bwachter.lart.info/linux/bridges.html) some hint (I can leave some of the ports to be used by server applications), but probably I misunderstood it.

Comment: @Orient  Let me just say that `br0`, once you have se it up, will work exactly like `eth0`, except that now you can use one of its ports (any port you choose, but normally it is 1194) to setup an OpenVPN server.